# how to change data in colums with python?

Tags: python, lambda

i want to replace some data on the table with python.
In the column stop,i want to replace :
non-stop with 0
1-stop with 1
2-stop with 2
im writing the command below but doesn't work

economy=economy.replace(['non-stop'],0)
should i use another command?

Comment: is this pandas? if so, i believe you are looking for economy.rename(columns={'non-stop': 0, ...})

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with replace, you would have to pass a dictionary, mapping the new and the old values:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

```
mapping = {
    "non-stop": 0,
    "1-stop": 1,
    ...
    }
economy = economy.replace(mapping)
```

Otherwise you could use string operators on the stop column

```
economy["stop"] = economy["stop"].str.replace("-stop", "").replace("non", "0")
```